# What is the difference between using ref vs ref.current within useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have the following ref variable :

```
const renderRefs = useRef()
```

What is the differenece beetween using:

```
  useEffect(() => {
   
  }, [renderRefs.current])
```

and

```
  useEffect(() => {
   
  }, [renderRefs])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you meant to refer to the same ref -

The ref object returned by `useRef` is stable. It will not change across re-renders. Since it's always the same, this

```
useEffect(() => {

}, [refItem])
```

is equivalent to

```
useEffect(() => {

}, [])
```

Whatever exists in the `.current` property of the ref may well change across re-renders, depending on how the ref is used. Putting the `.current` property in the dependency array means: "After a re-render, if the value has changed since the prior render, run the effect callback."

For example, if you had

```
<button
  onClick={() => {
    refItem.current = 5;
    setSomeState('abc');
  }}
  ...
```

clicking the button would result in a re-render due to `setSomeState`, and then if the ref value used to be something other than 5 on the last render, React will detect a change in the dependency array and run the effect callback.

If the ref value used to be 5 on the last render, then doing `refItem.current = 5` inside the click handler above means that the effect callback will *not* run after the next render, because the previous value of 5 is equal to the current value of 5.

Setting state is important. If you don't set state, the component won't re-render, and if the component doesn't re-render, the dependency array values aren't checked (nor does anything else occur). So, doing only

```
<button
  onClick={() => {
    refItem.current = 5;
  }}
  ...
```

is not sufficient to trigger the effect callback.

Comment: Was answering and created this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-platform-pb78bh?file=/src/App.js). Might help to illustrate what @CertainPerformance said.